# Purple lines in vim

Tags: vim

I've never seen this before in vim (although I haven't really used it much until now), and can't find anything in a google search for "purple lines vim".

So what to the purple lines shown in this screenshot mean?

[image: purple lines in vim]

I've just looked at a few other files in this project, which have similar PHP code in them, and cannot find the purple lines anywhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This lines are here because it's an HTML link. Your text is between   tags.

Comment: Thanks :) Will accept when it lets me

Comment: Wow I feel stupid now... "what could a underline between <a> tags possibly be"?